# Make Canvas element and all its children responsive for all screen sizes

Tags: canvas, responsive-design, fabricjs

I am using fabricJS to add an image into a canvas element as can be seen here:

http://jsfiddle.net/97nu2/

```
<canvas id="canvas" width="800" height="450" style="border:1px solid #000000"></canvas>

<script>
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');
fabric.Image.fromURL('http://s17.postimg.org/4740ku7z3/i_Stock_000000284123_XSmall.jpg', function (oImg) {
    // scale image down, and flip it, before adding it onto canvas
    oImg.scale(1);
    canvas.add(oImg);
});
</script>
```

I need this to be fully responsive to all screen sizes though so it will fit on tablets, smart phones etc. I know it's a requirement to define the width and height in the HTML.

Is it possible to resize the canvas element with css media queries or javascript while keeping all the images and elements inside the same ratio? Or do i have to create different canvases for each size?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to define the size of the canvas in the html. You can for example simply resize the canvas based on the screen size and then iterate over all canvas objects:

```
<canvas id="canvas" style="border:1px solid #000000"></canvas>

<script>
  var width = 800;
  var height = 450;
  var scaleFactor = 1;

  if(screen.width < 800) {
       scaleFactor = 0.8;
  } else if (screen.width > 1200) {
       scaleFactor = 1.2;
  } 

  width = width * scaleFactor;
  height = height * scaleFactor;

  var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');
  canvas.setWidth(width);
  canvas.setHeight(height);
  canvas.calcOffset();

  //Add Rectangles, Images etc...

  if(scaleFactor != 1) {
    for(var i=0; i<canvas._objects.length; i++){
       canvas._objects[i].scale(scaleFactor);   
       canvas._objects[i].setLeft(canvas._objects[i].left * scaleFactor); 
       canvas._objects[i].setTop(canvas._objects[i].top * scaleFactor);   
    }
    canvas.renderAll();
  }
</script>
```

if screen size doesn't fit your needs maybe you should try it with the window size. You also scale the objects before you are adding them to the canvas.In any case You probably also have to reposition the canvas elements after resizing them. Hope this helps. Benick

Comment: Thanks Benick but when i've placed your code into my page or jsfiddle it still doesn't update - new jsfiddle with your code here: http://jsfiddle.net/97nu2/1/

Comment: canvas._objects.length is 0 because the picture has not been added to the canvas yet. Try scaling it with the window size and scale the picture before you add it to the canvas. http://jsfiddle.net/97nu2/3/